# Questions about 「気をうしないかける」

Tags: manga, kansai-ben, compound-verbs

I came across the expression in manga which is said by a Kansai-speaking character.

> そのいいぐさはないやろ...ぶちのめされ**気をうしないかけて**いる人間によ!

I think the expression might have a similar meaning to the expression 「気を失う」 with a slight difference.

1. Is it the combination of two words of 「失う」 and 「掛ける」?
2. Why is 「い」 inserted between them?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34031/9831　・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28960/9831

Comment: `Why is 「い」 inserted between them?` <-- The continuative form
 /連用形 (or pre-masu form) of the verb 「失う」 is 「[失]{うしな} **い** 」.