# -かける in 出かける, 話しかける, 見かける, etc

Tags: compound-verbs

Verbs of the form V-始める mean 'begin to V'. Is there such a pattern for V-かける verbs?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34031/what-does-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%91-mean-in-%e3%81%93%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%8b%e3%81%91%e3%81%ae%e3%82%aa%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38193/correct-use-of-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%91%e3%81%a6/38195#38195

Comment: I’d say it’s a duplicate of the latter.